# How can I get the current date?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've done some researching, but I can't really find anything for the format that I'm wanting. Please go easy on me as this is my second day learning PHP and I'm working on a fairly large project to learn.

I have a SQL Database using the '**Date**' type, which follows the **yyyy-mm-dd** format.

My current SQL statement does this,

```
$query = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name (Date, Amount) VALUES ('now()', '$Amount')";
```

However, this doesn't update the date, and all of my entries are showing 0000-00-00

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Remove single quotes from around `now()`.... quotes mean treat it as a literal string

Comment: Worked, thanks. Post it as an answer and I'll greenlight it

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about typo in code and not useful for further visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also define your table to use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default value:

```
CREATE TABLE `example` (
  `created_at` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified_at` DATETIME ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

`DATETIME` can be used only from MySQL 5.6.5. In previous versions you need to use the `TIMESTAMP` type:

```
CREATE TABLE `example` (
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified_at` TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

Comment: This is the easier solution, and probably the better one for my related question.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name (Date, Amount) VALUES (now(), 123)";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the single quotes! Additionally you could use the `CURRENT_DATE` constant or create your table with `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 1):

There is many ways to do that.

### 1. Using the MySQL function "NOW()".

You can simply put `NOW()` on the place where date should be. `NOW()` is a MySQL function who return the date formated such as you request.

### 2. Using the PHP function "date()".

You can also use the `date()` function which comes with PHP, to perform what you want, juste wrote something like that :

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$query = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name (Date, Amount) VALUES ('$date', '$Amount')";
```